# "Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.", laravel 8 Api Resource

Tags: php, laravel, api, resources

### IN CONTROLLER ;

```
public function index()
{
    $conversations = Conversation::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('second_user_id',auth()->user()->id);
    
    $count = $conversations->get()->count();

    //
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            if ($conversations[$i]->messages->last()->id < $conversations[$j]->messages->last()->id) {
                $temp = $conversations[$i];
                $conversations[$i] = $conversations[$j];
                $conversations[$j] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }

 //  return  ConversationResource::collection($conversations);
 return  new ConversationResource($conversations);
}
```

App\Http\Resources\ConversationResource;

---

```
public function toArray($request)
{
  return [
    'id'=> $this->id,
    'created_at'=>$this->created_at,
    'message'=>MessageResource::collection($this->messages),
  ];
}
```

### USE App\Http\Resources\ConversationResource;

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);``
}
```

Comment: I believe that you need to execute that query in order to get data from column `id`.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `$conversations` is a Query Builder instance, not the result ... as Tra Lee was saying you need to execute the query and save that result to `$conversations` instead of passing around the Query Builder

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$conversations = Conversation::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('second_user_id',auth()->user()->id);
```

to this (add `get()` in the end):

```
$conversations = Conversation::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('second_user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

change the `$count` too:

```
$count = $conversations->count();
```

and change `return  new ConversationResource($conversations);` to:

```
return ConversationResource::collection($conversations);
```

Comment: Still getting this error "message": "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.",

The error appears to be the problem with defining variables that are not recognized in ConversationResource